# ruby on rails redirect_to with instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner in Ruby on Rails and want to understand how come redirect_to an instance variable.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  @article.save
  redirect_to @article
end
```

what does redirect_to @article imply?

Comment: its duplicate . . shall i delete the question ?

Comment: If you want to know how it actually passes an `id` to `show` action, try with printing the value of `@article` . (`@article.inspect`). It will returns the `id` parameter required for `show` action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It redirects (through Rails magic located in `url_for`, if I remember correctly) to article's `show` page.

Comment: where is this defined that it will redirect to article   /articles/:id   article#show. Is this by convention or some default mapping ? What happens if I redirect to only article with @symbol

Comment: Rails determine if it's article calling `@article.model_name`. So if you name your variable `@symbol`, it would still work.

Answer (score 2):

It means

```
 article   /articles/:id   article#show
```

It will redirect you to article's show action, check routes by executing rake routes

Notice the article GET /articles/:id articles#show - which gets matched when you do redirect_to(@article)

also read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: where is this defined that it will redirect to article   /articles/:id   article#show. Is this by convention or some default mapping ? What happens if I redirect to only article with @symbol

Comment: actually its not defined , but @article is a specific record with an id, so it will map with rake routes.

Answer (score 0):

**Resources**

This question can be better understood by reading into the [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) that Rails provides:

[image]

Conversely, as Rails is object / resource orientated, *every* method / function you run is based around resources, so this is just an extension of this idea.

--

When you use the likes of `redirect_to` or `render` with an object, Rails can take the object & pull down the corresponding routes for it.

Basically, if you have an `@article` object, Rails will observe that it's built from the `Article` model, and will consequently look for the `Articles` controller & the `show` method, to show a single resource on the page.

Hope this helps?